# Getting sum of column rows from two tables wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get the total of specific rows in a column from wordpress postmeta table.Its just like php,mysql query summation.But i am returning an empty array.

### Here is my codes:

```
global $wpdb;
$avg_ratings = 
"
    SELECT sum($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) 
    AS TotalRating
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'review_rating'  
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_title = get_the_title() 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'reviews'
";
$avg_rating = $wpdb->get_results( $avg_ratings, OBJECT );

print_r($avg_rating);
```

I am running this query in `WP_Query` so `get_the_title()` is automatically retrieved from `WP_query`.I am actually want to average the rating of `review_rating` meta-key values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
global $wpdb;
$title = get_the_title();
$avg_ratings = 
"
SELECT sum($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) 
AS TotalRating
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'review_rating'  
AND $wpdb->posts.post_title = '$title'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'reviews'
";
$avg_rating = $wpdb->get_results( $avg_ratings, OBJECT );

print_r($avg_rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
                        $wpdb->prepare("query", $some_parameter) 
                     );
```